# Can I receive Facebook group messages as email?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Is there a way I can interact with a Facebook group as a mailing list, without having to log into Facebook?  That is, be emailed all of the messages, and reply to the group via email?

Comment: First part is possible, the replying part is probably not

Comment: Does this work? https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook/replying-to-comments-through-email/206480947130/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable email notification for the messages from **Settings** -> **Notifications** -> **Email** -> select *All notifications, except the ones you unsubscribe from* option.

Replying to messages via email feature is off as of now.